# Ctrl+Alt+T is not pulling up a new terminal in Linux Mint Cinnamon 18.1

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to get working <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to run `gnome-terminal` as the command.

I've tried adding a new shortcut but to no avail.

I'm using a laptop keyboard and Left Ctrl typically. No color differentiation.

I've also tried the right one and combinations of left and right Alts as well but no terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happened to me too. Something (an update?) broke my locale.

To solve i did this:

- open menu -> languages
- set your language
- apply system wide
- reboot

Comment: That seems to have worked! I also updated my Mint shortly afterward and it seems to be working great now. Thanks!